# Alter submitted by text and retain RDF tags

Tags: theming, 7, rdf

I am looking to change the submitted by text from:

```
<span rel="sioc:has_creator" datatype="xsd:dateTime" content="2011-03-20T22:54:29+13:00" property="dc:date dc:created">Submitted by <a property="foaf:name" typeof="sioc:UserAccount" about="/users/author" xml:lang="" class="username" title="View user profile." href="/users/author">author</a> on Sun, 20/03/2011 - 22:54</span>
```

to:

```
<span datatype="xsd:dateTime" content="2011-03-20T22:54:29+13:00" property="dc:date dc:created">Date posted: 20 March 2011</span>
```

I know how to alter the text in node.tpl.php but I do not know the function that will return the date formatted with the RDF tags around it. Does anyone have experience in this area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function that returns the content of that tag is [date_iso8601()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/date_iso8601/7).
To understand how those tags are output, you should look at [rdf_preprocess_node()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--rdf--rdf.module/function/rdf_preprocess_node/7) and [rdf_process()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--rdf--rdf.module/function/rdf_process/7).